# Add META tag info for Facebook Instant Articles inside of js

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I have a website that is built on a customized CMS from a company (I think it's a chopped up version of WordPress or something) and they won't add in a simple line of code for a meta tag inside of our HTML.

I wanted to ask how I can insert Facebook's Instant Articles META tag into the one file our CMS company allows, which is an override.js.

Is this possible? If so, how could I do that? 
I simply need the following added:

```
<meta property="fb:pages" content="1234567890" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible.

The Facebook scraper tool that reads this meta data does not care for JavaScript; all the meta data has to be part of the HTML your system returns when the URL is requested.

Comment: Thanks so much for this!
Could this be done with CSS at all?